# Hibernate property not found error in xhtml file

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my class Where i am trying to persist data

```
 import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Data {
    private Members m;
    private  HibernateUtil help;
    private Session session ;

     public void addUser(){
         m = new Members("SumanthJois");
      session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      session.save(m);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      session.close();
     }


}
```

This my xhtml file where i am trying to add the data to the database on the button click! but when i click the button i am getting a error saying property not found!

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>

            <h:commandButton value="Add User" action="#{data.addUser()}"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Someone please help on how to call a function with xhtml?? whats wrong with my code??

Comment: your bean says `addUser()` but in your xhtml you are calling `#{data.addMember()}`

Comment: sorry its addUser in xhtml also

Comment: too bad :( I am not used to hibernate, but shouldn't you have some `@ManagedBean(name = "data")`  in your bean, so your container knows where to find `#{data.addUser()}`  ? If not, then I am afraid you have to look deeper into your logs or maybe debug, to see what *property* might be missing

Comment: no you dont do it that way!! anyway thankyou

Comment: Please add the exact error/exception you got ? You mentioned property not found but did not mentioned which property .So whenever you are asking some question its is better to add maximum thing related to question .

Comment: addUser() is the property missing